# .netCore email verify before seding

Tags: asp.net-core, mailkit

I'm looking for a method to  validate the email address before sending. On email  dns server.
I do **NOT** need regex or form email validation.
If user inputs test@google.com I want to know if there is an address like this on google server. I know there are some products that do the email validation. But we do not have money for that.

I'm using .netCore mailkit  as smptClient. I've saw that there is a verify method but it somehow does the call but never returns.

Can you help please?

Comment: You can't validate without sending an e-mail. That's why most websites send you a verification e-mail with a link you have to click. You can validate the domain I suppose by checking whether an MX DNS record exists for it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to validate an email address is to send an email to that address with a link the user must click. That link should have a token uniquely generated for the user. Your site, then, looks up the token from the user when the user visits your site with that link and marks the associated user's email as verified.

If you're using Identity, support for this is baked in. There's a [tutorial in the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=aspnetcore2x). Essentially, it involves just adding a line in your `AddIdentity` config in Startup.cs:

```
config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
```

Then, in your register action, you'd use the following to generate the URL for the link in the confirmation email:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
```

Next, just send the email to the user in any way you like. In your email confirmation action, the following confirms the email based on the code in the URL:

```
var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
```

**EDIT**

The `Url.EmailConfirmationLink` method actually comes from an extension added in the generated code when you add individual auth to a new project. Here's the code for that, for reference:

```
public static string EmailConfirmationLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string userId, string code, string scheme)
{
    return urlHelper.Action(
        action: nameof(AccountController.ConfirmEmail),
        controller: "Account",
        values: new { userId, code },
        protocol: scheme);
}
```

Comment: good answer but i cannot know that the email address u send the confirmation token is valid. For example mailGun have https://www.mailgun.com/email-validation . With this api you can validate that the email you are about to send is a valid email address. My questions if how can I do something like this?. I've saw this link https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Advanced-email-address-validation-in-NET but this valdiates as Wazner  says only the dns.

Comment: You know by the fact that user clicks the link, which they could not do if they did not receive the email (meaning it's a good address where they can receive email). There is simply no other way to validate an email address. The mailgun API may be keeping a record of previous successful email confirmations (relying on volume of usage to acquire a database of "good" emails), allowing to to "validate" an email without sending a new confirmation, but at some point, it would have had to be validated in the way described above at least once.

Comment: oh got it. Undersood now. Thank you a lot!